# sql server row number order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a below table in sql server 2014

```
Empno Resign      Hour Dept
1000  2999-01-01   40    20 
1000  2999-01-01   40    21
1001  2999-01-01   40    22
1001  2999-01-01   40    23
```

I need to pick a top record based on Resignation date and Hour. It doesn't matter row with which dept gets picked up. So I went with query

```
SELECT *
FROM( 
      SELECT Empno,Resign, Hour, Dept,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Empno ORDER BY Resign DESC,
                                                                    hour DESC) AS Row
      FROM Table ) AS master
WHERE master.Row = 1
  AND master.Empno = '1000';
```

I got back with

```
EmployeeNumber  ResignationDate Hour Dept   Row
1000               2999-01-01   40     20    1
```

I understand sql server doesn't guarantee the order(in this case row with which dept) of the row number unless an order by clause is specified for the Dept.

I dont mind which row with which dept gets picked up but would this happen consistently to pick one, based on some index or id, how would the top would be produced by the query plan?

In the row_number I can simply add another orderby based on dept so that it consistently picks up one but I dont want to do that.

Comment: Interesting.. Have you come across this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx#General%20Remarks ?

Comment: @Searching yep i did read through **There is no guarantee that the rows returned by a query using ROW_NUMBER() will be ordered exactly the same with each execution unless the following conditions are true.**

Comment: Thanks @Searching i think its straight forward that there is no way to be deterministic about the columns not in order by

Comment: yeah no guarantee when there are ties and I have seen variations depending on index differences etc for the same result set, but generally if you hit the same index and have the same columns you will typically get the same answer.  Integers usually ascending, etc...  If you want to guarantee random (or more random) you can add NEWID() at the end of the ORDER BY and it will randomly choose between the records but even that is somewhat incremental as well.

Comment: I can't figure out what the question is.  Your description seems accurate.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to add another order by clause? It seems the right solution to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** You have to add `order by` with unique combination to force non-arbitrary output.

And why? Its easy question - sql server don't see tables as human. He reads and finds pages which not may not be near or in a row.